# According to DDD do i need additional repository and model

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

According to `DDD` for each `aggregate` i have `repository`. Let's take an example:

```
Client (model aggregate) > ClientRepository
Visit  (model aggregate)  > VisitRepository
```

Now phisicly i have association table in database which connects Client and Visit because clients could have many visists.

The question is: Should i create separated model like: `ClientVisit` which also would be an `aggregate`:

```
public class ClientVisit
{
     int clientId;
     int visitId;   
}
```

Also s repository like `ClientVisitRepository` which could reference/use `ClientRepository` and `VisitRepository`.

Or is it enough to stick with e.g `CLientRepository` and get data from there without additionality model and repository

**Modification to the post:**

Instead of `Visit` (wrong example) - let's replace by `Car` therefore each `client` can have `many cars`. We would have also unique `transactionNumber` so:

```
Client (model aggregate)  > ClientRepository
Car    (model aggregate)  > CarRepository
```

Should then i then create aggregate such as:

```
public class ClientCar
{
    int clientId;
    int visitId;  
    int transactionNumber; 
}
```

and `ClientCarRepository`?

Comment: What are you storing in the Visit aggregate?

Comment: @SirRufo VisitId, Name, ReferenceNumber and other things. Remember its aggregate no VO

Comment: I also consider put List<int> Visits into Client's model because if client can have many visists i could make proerty of int (int because Visit is aggregate so cannot use directly Visit type). in this way i could then use ClientRepository. Not sure ?

Comment: But why a list? I would simply add the ClientId to it. When a new Visit is done then it is a new Visit

Comment: @SirRufo i dont understand. Question is if there is association between two aggregates - is it fine to create additional model and repository or not ? Or maybe just to create ClientVisistRepository which consumes both ClientRepository and VisitRepository ? That would make sense i think. Of course ClientVisit model should be created containg both clientId and visitid

Comment: When I visit a location then this visit is unique, even when I will visit it several times, then each of this visits is unique => each visit get a new VisitId and each Visit has a single LocationId and a single PersonId and not a list of anything

Comment: @SirRufo maybe i gave wrong example with that Visit. Imagine then not Visit but Car. So each client can have many Cars in his collection. besides each car also would have specific unique serial number. Car is aggregate of course. How would you then accomplish that?

Comment: Would you like to talk about the cars or about your question?

Comment: @SirRufo i modified question. Let's talk about such situation - that's what i initially had on mind.

Comment: Ok, in **this** case you have a ClientCar aggregate/repository, but no access to the Client or Car repository.

Comment: @SirRufo sorry again i made mistake - you right serial number would belong to Car - therefore i put transactionNumber

Comment: As I told, the answer is: Yes

Comment: @SirRufo So this means i would have as i proposed ClientCar aggregate class containing only ids as reference to client and car (ids because car and client are aggregates therefore from my knowledge in this case i could not put their types in ClientCar but their ids? Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @SirRufo Hmm, i am not sure also whether ClientCar should contain either: ClientID, CarId,TransactionNr or : ClientId, Dictionary<int, int> cars; ? What would you suggest?

Comment: I do not know what you are going to solve with your ClientCar, but in DDD you have to be very clear about that. So please go a step back, think what you are going to solve and then come back, update your question and we can start over

Comment: @SirRufo i think my ClientCar will have: ClientId, List<int> cars (storing car ids..) Last question: If i create ClientCarRepository - can thi repository use existing CarRepository and ClientRepository or it's forbidden?

Comment: How many times should I mention it? Is one time enough? Then read my comments

Answer (score 1):

No, don't use a different repository for each entity or aggregate. You are not applying DDD completely in your modelling. You have to focus on the Ubiquitous language. Let me explain.

Repositories are meant to be nothing more than serializers and de-serializers for your entities and aggregates. There shouldn't be an intentional 1-to-1 between them. In fact, most of the time you won't have the 1-to-1. In my code, I tend to scope repositories to the bounded context or to a subcontext.

Take a trivial example: A blogging application. I might have a repository that can persist a comment. Persisting the comment means saving the comment itself and updating User's comment count. The `Save(Comment comment, Usr usr)` method will make two calls to my persistence mechanism to update the individual Entities or Aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

`Repository`, in the sense of domain driven design, is a life cycle management pattern.  See chapter 6 of the "blue book".

It's purpose is to isolate from our application code the strategy we are using to store and retrieve aggregate roots.  That's important, because the aggregate roots are the only parts of the domain code that our application code talks to directly.

From this, it follows that you don't need a repository for the client car relation *unless it is the root of its own aggregate*.

Figuring out whether this relation should be in its own aggregate or not is a matter of domain analysis -- you're going to have to dig into your specific domain to figure out the answer.  For something like a car rental domain, I would *guess* that you'll want this relation, and the information associated with its life cycle, to be in a separate aggregate from the car or the customer.  But I wouldn't feel confident in that guess until I had worked through a few edge cases with the domain experts.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you treat an entity as aggregate root, thereby introduce a corresponding repository, depends on your domain or its *ubiquitous language*. One of the key indicators of aggregates is that they encapsulate important domain *operations*.

Hard to be precise without knowing your domain, however, in your example, `Client` seems to be a more natural candidate for an aggregate: a client may *own new cars*, *get rid of a few*, etc; the corresponding operations (i.e. adding cars or removing cars) fit naturally into client.

`ClientCar` (or `ClientVisit`), on the other hand, doesn't seem to have any purpose other than *retrieving cars owned by a client*. For this purpose, *navigating the entity* should suffice, no aggregate is necessary. Your `Client` repository may introduce a method for this purpose like the following:

```cs
public interface ClientRepository
{
    Client findById(String clientId);

    void store(Client client);

    IList<Cars> carsOwnedBy(String clientId);
}
```

Then `carsOwnedBy` method implementation retrieves a `Client` and returns only the `Car`s associated with it.

Comment: The list returned by carsOwnedBy will be passed to the Client aggregate?